# Vertical and horizontal align anchor element, area clickable 100% of parent

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

How would one vertically and horizontally center an anchor tag within a parent block or inline-block level element (div or button), while making the clickable area of the anchor 100% the width and height of the parent element?

I've achieved the desired goal using flexbox, however, I'd like to know how I can do so w/out using flexbox or grid.
Below is an example of the effect using flexbox.

```css
.medium-button {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #3a66db;
  padding: 0;
}

.medium-button__link {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 160px;
  height: 48px;
}
```

```html
<button class="medium-button">
  <a class="medium-button__link">
    Clickable link
  </a>
</button>
```

Comment: Please don’t nest interactive elements, like an `a`- in a `button`-element. That is invalid HTML.

Comment: thank you, is the answer below a suitable solution for the problem? To clarify, could I use the flexbox solution above using an `a` nested in a `div`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, thanks to @insertusernamehere, an `<a/>` inside a `<button/>` isn't valid HTML. 
That helped simplify the markup to be an anchor tag that looks like and interacts as a button, instead of having nested elements.

--> simply set the anchor tag as a block-level element so you can specify width and height, then use line-height.

```css
.medium-button__link {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 48px;  
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 48px;
    background: #3a66db;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'OpenSans-Regular';
    font-size: 1em;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
  
<a class="medium-button__link" href="https://sirthisisawendys.com">
    Clickable link
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using flex property you can achieve the vertical and horizontal align anchor element. Actually whenever you gave the height of element you have to give same **LINE-HEIGHT** on that element. The line-height property specifies the height of a line. So You have to use same line height on medium-button__link div.

Answer (score 0):

u can do this with display table on the `<a>` tag and `width:100%` and `height:100%`
then add for span children: `display: table-cell` and  `vertical-align: middle`

```css
.medium-button {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #3a66db;
   width: 160px;
  height: 48px;
  padding: 0;
}

.medium-button__link {
 width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:table;
   text-align:bottom;
}
span{
 display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<button class="medium-button">
  <a class="medium-button__link">
    <span>Clickable link</span>
  </a>
</button>
```